# Why getting error "'CalendarsRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' " graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to write code to access Microsoft Calendar using Graph API

```
    var calendars = await graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();
    List<string> calendarNames = new List<string>();
       foreach (var calendar in calendars)
       {
         calendarNames.Add(calendar.Name);
       }
```

I am facing strange problem.

`var calendars = await graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();`

But compiler is throwing error saying  "'CalendarsRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' "

I have nuget packages included

`Microsoft.Graph Microsoft.Graph.Core Microsoft.Idendity.Client`

I tried downgrading Graph library, but problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Request()` method is used in Graph SDK v4, the latest SDK v5 removed this method, so you can call directly `GetAsync()`

```
await graphClient.Me.Calendars.GetAsync();
```

To get access token (based on your comment)

- create a new class that implements `IAccessTokenProvider`
- in `GetAuthorizationTokenAsync` create `IPublicClientApplication`

```
public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "Calendar.ReadWrite" };
        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        var publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("clientId").Build();
        try
        {

            var accounts = await publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            authResult = await publicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            authResult = await publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, create a new authentication provider

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

[Upgrade guide from v4 to v5](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)

Comment: Thanks USer2250152.   Can you also help me with following code that is showing error.  
 with 'DelegateAuthenticationProvider'  could not be found error....  var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
     new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
         requestMessage =>
         {
             requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
             return Task.FromResult(0);
         }));

Comment: How do you get authResult? You can check the [doc](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/tokencredentials.md). There is a way to implement [custom token provider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication)

Comment: var scopes = new string[] { "Calendars.Read" };
   AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
   try
   {  authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();   }
   catch (MsalException ex)
   {   }
   if (authResult != null)
   {       var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
           new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
               requestMessage =>
               {                   requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                   return Task.FromResult(0);    }));

Comment: @TeamFreytag Updated the answer with the code how to create new authentication provider. But it would be better to create a new question in case of any problem, so other users can answer it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help user2250152. You are great!  :)